# How to get dropped file names in PyQt/PySide

Tags: python, events, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyside

I am trying to set up an application that will accept havin files dropped into it.  So, I am looking for a way to extract the path when they are dropped in.

Right now, I have drag and drop enabled for the right part of the application, and it will accept text dropped in, but I do not know how to handle having a file dropped in.

I am using:

```
def PTE_dragEnterEvent(self, e):
    if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/plain'):
        e.accept()
    else:
        e.ignore() 

def PTE_dropEvent(self, e):
    newText = self.ui.fileListPTE.toPlainText() + '\n\n' + e.mimeData().text()
    self.ui.fileListPTE.setPlainText(newText)
```

Which is slightly modifying the code provided in the [Zetcode Drag and Drop  tutorial](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/dragdrop/).

---

I couldn't quite get @ekhumoro answer to work for me, but it gave me more places to look, and I found [Drag and drop files into QListWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4151637/984421) which helped.

In addition to the suggestions made by ekhumoro I needed to implement the drag move event.  What I finally used looked like:

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
        
def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

def dropEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        event.accept()
        
        newText = self.ui.fileListPTE.toPlainText()
        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            newText += '\n' + str(url.toLocalFile())
        self.ui.fileListPTE.setPlainText(newText)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("dropped"))
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

Comment: I think `hasUrls` is a function, so your conditions that use it always evaluate to `True`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [QMimeData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html) class has methods for dealing with dropped urls. Below is a minimal working example:

```
# from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QLabel
# from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

class Window(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        print('drag-enter')
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            print('has urls')
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        lines = []
        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            lines.append('dropped: %r' % url.toLocalFile())
        self.setText('\n'.join(lines))
    
app = QApplication(['Drag & Drop'])
window = Window()
window.setGeometry(50, 100, 400, 300)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

**UPDATE**:

Regarding the additions to the question:

Some widgets (unlike the `QLabel` used above) have a default implementation of `dragMoveEvent` that explicitly ignores most events. For example, classes based on `QAbstractItemView` may only handle certain kinds of internal move and ignore everything else. In which case, a reimplementation of `dragMoveEvent` should be added that explicitly accepts the events that need to be handled differently:

```
class MyView(QTableView):
    ...
    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            super().dragMoveEvent(event)
```

Comment: So I noticed if I drop a file in and print event.mimeData().urls() it returns values like `/.file/id=6571367.6613263`, which I believe are some sort of OSX temporary files. Wondering, how would one go about getting the proper filename or directory as opposed to this sort of temporary marker?