# How to handle "drag and drop a file" event to cv2.imshow() window

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to drag and drop an image file to `cv2.imshow()` window and fetch the filename path.

There is no event named drag and drop and I need some help.

In my project I remove the background image and I want to change the background with any image.

I did the hard part (removing the background) but I don't know how to handle drag/drop files event in OpenCV python.

```
def mouse_events(event, x,y, flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_??: # ?? drag/drop a file event
        # return the filename

while True:
   ...
   cv2.setMouseCallback(windowName, mouse_events)
   ...
```

[image: handle drag/drop event]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you **can't**. OpenCV is a library for computer vision, with some convenience for displaying images. you want a **library for GUI programming**.

Comment: as you found out, there is no such event built into the imshow() code. there is also no clipboard handling of any kind , so it simply wont work. maye you can fire up the stdio input() function on the console , and drop your file there, not on the gui window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Christoph Rackwitz pointed out, you cannot do this using OpenCV alone. You have to use some GUI programming interface such as `PyQt5` or `pyside`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568500/how-to-get-dropped-file-names-in-pyqt-pyside) demonstrates drag and drop functionality with file explorer.

Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DxN8G9vB50) for integrating with OpenCV

Comment: Thanks for answering.... Finally, I replaced `imshow()` with `Tkinter` then I handled DnD with it.