# PyQt - object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5, and I want to make a Drag&Drop system.

I got the code on this post : [PyQT4: Drag and drop files into QListWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151637/pyqt4-drag-and-drop-files-into-qlistwidget)

When I Run, I got the following error :  AttributeError: 'MainForm' object has no attribute 'connect'

The code:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class TestListView(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(TestListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(72, 72))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.emit(Qt.SIGNAL("dropped"), links)
        else:
            event.ignore()

class MainForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = TestListView(self)
        self.connect(self.view, Qt.SIGNAL("dropped"), self.pictureDropped)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def pictureDropped(self, l):
        for url in l:
            if os.path.exists(url):
                print(url)
                icon = QIcon(url)
                pixmap = icon.pixmap(72, 72)
                icon = QIcon(pixmap)
                item = QListWidgetItem(url, self.view)
                item.setIcon(icon)
                item.setStatusTip(url)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an old form of connection, you must update the following things:

create the signal:

```
class TestListView(QListWidget):
    dropped = pyqtSignal(list)
```

Also change:

```
self.emit(Qt.SIGNAL("dropped"), links)
```

to:

```
self.dropped.emit(links)
```

And change:

```
self.connect(self.view, Qt.SIGNAL("dropped"), self.pictureDropped)
```

to:

```
self.view.dropped.connect(self.pictureDropped)
```

For more information you can read [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)

Complete code:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class TestListView(QListWidget):
    dropped = pyqtSignal(list)
    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(TestListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(72, 72))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            links = []
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                links.append(str(url.toLocalFile()))
            self.dropped.emit(links)
        else:
            event.ignore()

class MainForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.view = TestListView(self)
        self.view.dropped.connect(self.pictureDropped)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

    def pictureDropped(self, l):
        for url in l:
            if os.path.exists(url):
                print(url)
                icon = QIcon(url)
                pixmap = icon.pixmap(72, 72)
                icon = QIcon(pixmap)
                item = QListWidgetItem(url, self.view)
                item.setIcon(icon)
                item.setStatusTip(url)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How could I use this with a QWidget instead of a QListWidget ?

Comment: If I want to inherit from a QWidget instead of a QListWidget, what do I need to change ?